# Inconsistent TS2345 when passing function paramter in different ways

Tags: typescript

I defined an interface named AAA and it has only one member and using the AAA as the function parameter's declaration. When I pass a **defined** constant variable with two members, the typescript can't detect. However when I pass a literal variable typescript can detect the extra paramter. I don't understand the difference, did someone encounter similar situation？

```
interface AAA {
  hyYears: Array<any>;
}

function func(process: AAA) {
  console.log(process);
}

const unresolveParams = {
  hyYears: [],
  periodDataId: 1,
};


func(unresolveParams); // why this line can't detect the extra parameter

func({
  hyYears: [],
  periodDataId: 1, // detect the extra parameter. Argument of type '{ hyYears: undefined[]; periodDataId: number; func(unresolveParams: any): any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AAA'. ts(2345)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript generally performs [structural type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out). It doesn't care if an object has extra properties bolted on.

Object literals get special treatment and are subject to [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) since creating an object and then immediately assigning it somewhere which isn't expecting the `periodDataId` property is more likely to be an error.

Comment: Thanks!!!  Would you explain it more elaborately like why ts design the deffierence?

Comment: I think what I've already written is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: I did read the content from the two links but still don't know why ts makes it different. I mean why structal type check doesn't care if an object has extra properties in this case...